# How to Bind Kendo UI Button To Show Show if a Combobox is Dirty

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

I have been searching far and wide and cannot seem to find an answer. I am using Kendo UI JavaScript framework to make a simple `ComboBox` and a single (initially disabled) `Button`. If the `ComboBox` is changed, I want to make the `Button` enabled. If the `ComboBox` is changed back to the original value, I want to disabled the `Button`. Basically, if the `ComboBox` is dirty, I want to enable the button -- otherwise the button should be disabled.

**Issue:**

I obviously can just attach a `change` listener to the `ComboBox`, and if the value is now dirty call `j$('#submitButton').enable(true)` and if not dirty I can call `j$('#submitButton').enable(false)`. *But I cannot seem to find how to check is value is dirty or not.* This seems very simple, but I cannot find the answer. Maybe I can manually decorate the `ComboBox` with the original value? How would I go about doing that?

**HTML:**

```
<td>
    <h5>Brand</h5>
    <div id="combo1"></div>
</td>
<td>
    <h5>Color</h5>
    <div id="combo2"></div>
</td>
<em id="submitButton"><span class="k-sprite">Submit</span></em>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
j$("#combo1").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    value: "Original_Brand_Value",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "..."
            }
        }
    }
});
j$("#combo2").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "id",
    value: "Original_Color_Value",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "..."
            }
        }
    }
});
j$("#submitButton").kendoButton({
    spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-close"
});
```

Comment: Why can't you use `change: onChange` event of Combobox and make the button visible

Comment: I can do that, but I cannot find the way to determine if the `ComboBox` is dirty or not. Can you please re-read what I say under the "Issue" heading. I describe this situation.

Comment: There is a `hasChanges` method to identify any change in Datasource, check the link: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-hasChanges

Comment: This method does not work for my purpose. This is not a check if the value of the ComboBox is dirty. This only checks if a record within the combobox data store has changed. I am not editing any data within the combobox store, I am just changing the selection which record is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to identify the changes in datasource. Usually we use this for Kendo grids

```
if ($("#combo1").data('kendoComboBox').dataSource.hasChanges())
{
//Data Changed
}
```

Comment: This method does not work for my purpose. This is not a check if the value of the `ComboBox` is dirty. This only checks if a record *within the combobox data store* has changed. I am not editing any data within the combobox store, I am just changing the selection which record is selected.